# Matrix exponential with given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help me with this question?

I'm trying to understand what a matrix exponential is, but I don't know if I'm doing it right. I need a solution, please.

Here's the question:
[image]

Comment: Don’t include key parts of your question as images. They’re not searchable and are inaccessible to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix exponential is defined as follows:
$$e^A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{n!}=I+A+\frac{A^2}{2}+\frac{A^3}{6}+\cdots$$ In order to calculate the matrix exponential, therefore, we have to be able to calculate $A^n$ for each $n.$ In general this is hard, but you will find that for your matrix, $A^n=0$ for all $n\geq 3$, so all but the first few terms are zero. So you need to calculate $A^2$ and then $$e^A=I+A+\frac{A^2}{2}+0+0+\cdots$$